# How to get a radio question answer text using jQuery in SurveyJS

Tags: surveyjs

I am trying to capture a radio type question answer when user completes the SurveyJS form. I can only able to get the radio type question answer value but I am looking for text value using jQuery... please share your thoughts on this.

Example:
"choices": [
{
"value": "Item 1",
"text": "Development required"
},
{
"value": "Item 2",
"text": "Not assessed"
},
{
"value": "Item 3",
"text": "Not observed"
},
{
"value": "Item 4",
"text": "Satisfactory - needs attention"
}
]

```html
{
            var page = response.visiblePages[i];
            var questions = page.questions;
            
            for (var j = 0; j < questions.length; j++) 
            {
                var question = questions[j];
                questionNumber = question.name;
                elements[questionNumber] = response.data[question.name];
                if(questionNumber == "Question43")
                {
                    alert(response.data[question.name]);
                }
            }
        for (var i = 0; i < response.visiblePages.length; i++) 
        {
            var page = response.visiblePages[i];
            var questions = page.questions;
            
            for (var j = 0; j < questions.length; j++) 
            {
                var question = questions[j];
                questionNumber = question.name;
                elements[questionNumber] = response.data[question.name];
                if(questionNumber == "Question_Outcome")
                {
                    alert(response.data[question.name]);
                }
            }
```

using the above snippet, I am able to receive the answer Value ("Item1") but I am expecting text ("Development required")